# Update Data Structure - Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, database, postgresql, database-design, spring-data-jpa

Propose the given situation :

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final String data;

    public Data(Double in) {
        this.data = String.valueOf(in);
    }
}
```

A future update decides on a restructure :

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private final Double data;

    public Data(Double in) {
        this.data = in;
    }
}
```

How would one elegantly update previous data using the Spring Starter JPA?

Comment: Is Data an ‘@Entity in JPA terms? Does the field _data_ have a backing column that starts off as a VARCHAR and later is a DECIMAL? Please clarify the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @JohnWilliams The Data class is used within a field of a tagged entity.